# Kan extension diagram in tikzcd

Tags: tikz-arrows, tikz-cd

I am trying to draw the following picture using tikzcd[image]
and here is my current attempt:

```
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzcd}[row sep=huge, column sep=huge]
    % drawing 0- and 1-celss
    \mathcal{C}  \arrow[dr, "\mathcal{F}"', ""{name=F}]
    \arrow[rr, "\mathcal{H}", ""{name=H, below}] &&
    \mathcal{E} \\
    & \mathcal{D} \arrow[ur, swap, dashed, "\operatorname{Lan}_{\mathcal{F}}\mathcal{H}", ""{name=Lan, above}]
    %
    % drawing 2-cells  
    \arrow[Rightarrow, from=H, to=Lan, "\eta"]
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

However, I cannot get the middle "double arrow" as in the above picture. How can I fix this in the current code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define an `alias` to define the target. This has the advantage over using the row and column indices that it will still work when you extend the diagram.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=huge, column sep=huge] 
 % drawing 0- and 1-celss 
 \mathcal{C} \arrow[dr, "\mathcal{F}"'{name=F}] 
 \arrow[rr, "\mathcal{H}", ""{name=H, below}] && \mathcal{E} \\ 
 & |[alias=D]| \mathcal{D} \arrow[ur, swap, dashed,
 "\operatorname{Lan}_{\mathcal{F}}\mathcal{H}"] 
 % % drawing 2-cells
 \arrow[Rightarrow, from=H, to=D, "\eta",shorten >=1em,shorten <=1em] 
\end{tikzcd} 
\end{document}
```

[image]